# How do you put a hyperlink into a multiline text field?

Tags: 2007, rich-text, hyperlink, multiline-text-field

When typing text into a multiline rich text field, I want to put some hyperlinks in.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to proceed in two steps:

1/ Enter the URL: http://... SharePoint will automatically convert it into a hyperlink. It will change the look to blue underlined text.

2/ Select the whole URL and overwrite it with your own description. SharePoint will keep the underlying URL and you'll get your final hyperlink.

Comment: Step 1 worked great.  Sorry for taking so long to get back to this.

Comment: Step 2 works only if the multiline field is in rich text mode.

Answer (score 0):

There should be an icon of the world with a grey link/chain across the bottom of it in the rich text toolbar. Otherwise, select some text and press `Ctrl+K`.

Comment: No Icon and Ctrl+K doesn't do anything.

Comment: Well, I'm guessing that I'll have to upgrade the field to Enhanced Rich Text, which will cause me to have to do a bunch of javascript work to get the page to display right, but I don't see any other way.  Too many Microsoft compromises make for a tough development path.

Comment: Afraid so. I didn't realise the "standard" rich text box couldn't do it. By the way, at least one reason why there is a difference is so browser support - e.g. Firefox doesn't display enhanced rich text boxes in SP 2007.